# No BitLocker bootup passphrase

Tags: windows, windows-10, encryption, bitlocker, disk-encryption

When I have BitLocker enabled on my old computer, I get a blue screen asking for the passphrase when I boot it up.  However, I have noticed on newer computers, the drive is encrypted but doesn't ask for the bootup BitLocker passphrase.

How do I enable BitLocker on a new computer so it does not ask for a passphrase when booting up?

I have done a clean install of Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit on the new computer.

The computer is a Latitude 7490 and it seems to have TPM based on the [owners manual](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/uk/en/ukbsdt1/latitude-14-7490-laptop/latitude_7490_om/security-screen-options?guid=guid-37d4e9bc-2c83-4b96-8230-21f096628f93&lang=en-us):

Comment: I will check and update the question as soon as I find the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @Ramhound, updated the question.  It seems the new hardware has TPM.

Comment: @Ramhound, I am happy with any option.  As long as the drive is encrypted and ideally, doesn't ask for a decryption passphrase + a user login passphrase/password.  Not sure which option is the best based on my hardware.  So does this mean with TPM enabled, the drive is already encrypted?  How do I confirm this without physically taking the drive out and trying to read it from another computer?  Main goal, if laptop is stolen, no one should be able to read the drive and ideally, the user should not have to type in multiple passwords to load the laptop.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use the Group Policy Editing tooling.

You should take note of Steps 5 and 11-13 in the linked article below for a pictural representation of the steps needed, this also allows for no password prompt, but can use a usb or hardware token (enabling silent static password even).

[1] https://hardsoft-support.kayako.com/article/55-how-to-use-bitlocker-drive-encryption-on-windows-10